# Compare two JSON files

Tags: json, compare, cypress

I am trying to compare two JSON files in Cypress.

To see if this works I simply made a copy of `data.json` and renamed its copy to `data2.json`.

```
var comparejson = cy.readFile('data2.json')
cy
  .readFile('data.json')
  .then(json => JSON.stringify(json)).should('eq', JSON.parse(comparejson))
```

This is the error I get:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the dreaded `token o`. It's reading the 'o' from `[object Object]`, which is the `toString` representation of a Plain Ol' JavaScript Object.

You can test this for yourself, by the way, by entering a JavaScript REPL and:

```
08:54 $ node
Welcome to Node.js v13.0.1.
Type ".help" for more information.
> JSON.parse({}.toString())
Thrown:
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
> ({}).toString()
'[object Object]'
```

So in the future, any time you see that error you know you've skipped a step in stringifying somewhere!

The trick here is that `readFile` returns an object (not a string, JSON files are [parsed by Cypress into JavaScript](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/readfile.html#JSON)) but you're calling `JSON.parse` on the object.

Try this:

```
cy
  .readFile('data2.json')
  .then(data2 => cy.readFile('data.json').should('deep.equal', data2))
```

Note use of `deep.equal` here, since we're comparing objects.